# Omit curly braces when using .map in Pandas to create a column from a dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I'm not sure if my title is clear enough, but I have the following issue: I want to use `.map` to create a new column from a dictionary in my dataframe. This is working as intended, except for one problem: the function extracts a whole string with curly braces from the dictionary, instead of just the values. I googled extensively and couldn't find a tutorial that would lead to a different result or an answer to this question. Example:

df:

```
  col1
0  a
1  b
2  c
```

dict:

```
{ a : {'value' : 2},
  b : {'value' : 4},
  c : {'value' : 1}}
```

Now I want to use .map to create a new column with values that correspond to col1, like this:

```
  col1  col_new
0  a       2
1  b       4
2  c       1
```

Instead, what I get is this:

```
  col1     col_new
0  a    {'value' : 2}
1  b    {'value' : 4}
2  c    {'value' : 1}
```

This is the .map command that I use:

```
df["new_col"] = df.col1.map(dict)
```

I tried using `to_numeric`, but that didn't have any effect and I guess that it doesn't have anything to do with numeric/string types of data.

Any help would be appreciated, as a self-taught data analyst who is just starting out with Python, I still have trouble finding the answers in the documentation sometimes.

Comment: Side note: it is a bad idea to name your dictionary `dict`. It overrides the functionality of inbuilt [dict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict).

Comment: I don't actually call it that, it was mostly for the purposes of this simple example. Thanks for the info though, I wasn't aware and I might have done that at some point in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's happening is your dictionary values are themselves dictionaries.

So `pd.Series.map` will only map to dictionary values. It can't do anything else. There are some workarounds.

#### Use itemgetter to extract values

This will extract the value for the "value" key in each dictionary.

```
from operator import itemgetter

df['new_col'] = df['col1'].map(d).apply(itemgetter('value'))
```

#### Restructure your dictionary before mapping

Construct a new dictionary with the key-mapping your desire before mapping your series.

```
d = {k: v['value'] for k, v in d.items()}
df['new_col'] = df['col1'].map(d)
```

Comment: This makes sense, so maybe we can rewind to how the dictionary was initially created from a dataframe and fix this procedure first:

`dfA.set_index("col_abc").T.to_dict("dict")`

Comment: @DataWiz, Sure, but note that `pd.Series.map` can be used with *another series* directly. You probably don't need a dictionary at all.

Comment: Anything I can modify about this code? `dfA` has 2 columns, the first of which is `col_abc`, used to create the index of the dictionary, and the second of which is `value`, used for the values. Right now this code adds the column name to each value, creating what you described as a dictionary within a dictionary.

Comment: Just use `s = dfA.set_index('col_abc')['value']` and then `df['new_col'] = df['col1'].map(s)`.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you intend to reconstruct your `dict` before `.map()`, the below approach would fit.

```
df['new_col'] = df['col1'].apply(lambda x: dict_[x]['value'])
```

Output:

```
  col1  new_col
0   a   2
1   b   4
2   c   1
```

Answer (score 0):

That values in the dictionary are set to the column of dataframe

```
dic = { 'a' : 2, 'b' : 4, 'c' : 1}
df["new_col"] = df.col1.map(dict)
```

This should work fine.